# What prominent Nietzsche experts give 'empathy' a role to play in his transvaluation?

Tags: ethics, nietzsche

What prominent Nietzsche experts give 'empathy' a role to play in his trans-valuation? I [found](https://scholarworks.gsu.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1210&context=philosophy_theses) a paper that lists proponents of the opposite view, but it is not peer reviewed, and is just a Masters thesis.

> Moral philosophers like **Martha Nussbaum, Philippa Foot, and Michael
>   Weber** argue for what I call the “Neo-Stoic Reading” of Nietzsche,
>   which includes two claims: first, Nietzsche allegedly recommends the
>   relentless pursuit of self-interest at the expense of other
>   persons;second, *he denies empathy any major role* in the ethical life

Emphasis added: I'm just looking for alternatives.

Comment: It helps to look under the top Google result. Ganesh's paper based on his thesis you linked [was published](https://www.jstor.org/stable/10.5325/jnietstud.48.2.0219). And even [IEP](https://www.iep.utm.edu/emp-symp/#SH4a) "gives empathy a role".  Two more, using "compassion": [Harris, Compassion and Affirmation in Nietzsche](https://www.jstor.org/stable/10.5325/jnietstud.48.1.0017), [Frazer, The Compassion  of Zarathustra](https://dash.harvard.edu/bitstream/handle/1/3350069/Frazer_Compassion.pdf?...)

Comment: hm, less there than i would have liked... no well known scholars then @Conifold i guess the issue for me is that amoral people just end up seeming a little petty -- though that does seem a judgment of taste